# How to convert this list into a dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
list1 = ['ip1 = 10.105.236.24,\n', 'ip2 = 10.105.236.25,\n', 'ip3 = 10.104.235.1\n', '\n']
```

How can i convert the above list into a dictionary like this?

```
{ "ip1"): "10.105.236.24", ... }
```

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
>>> dict([x.strip().split("=") for x in list1 if "=" in x])
{'ip3 ': ' 10.104.235.1', 'ip1 ': ' 10.105.236.24,', 'ip2 ': ' 10.105.236.25,'}
```

I added `strip()` to get rid of the trailing newline, too.

Comment: You'll need to take away the comma, too

Comment: To remove spaces and comma too, use `dict([x.strip().replace(',','').split(" = ") for x in list1 if " = " in x])`

Answer (score 0):

Split each element by the `'='` character, create a new `list` of each pair, and pass it to the `dict` constructor.